# MySQL if / else statement dependent on MySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need some help I am a bit stuck:

I would like it so that IF a row in a table equals YES then it displays a certain image, however IF that row in the table equals NO then it displays another image.

Do you have any ideas?

```
if($fetch["g1"] == 1) $buffer .= 'Group 1, '; 
if($fetch["g2"] == 1) $buffer .= 'Group 2, '; 
if($fetch["g3"] == 1) $buffer .= 'Group 3, '; 

echo substr($buffer,0,-2).' ';
```

Comment: Not without more information.  Do you have an existing query or a table structure?

Comment: `if($fetch["g1"] == 1)
 $buffer .= 'Group 1, ';
if($fetch["g2"] == 1)
 $buffer .= 'Group 2, ';
if($fetch["g3"] == 1)
 $buffer .= 'Group 3, ';
echo substr($buffer,0,-2).' ';`

But at the moment that only displays text if the value is true

Comment: You should make changes/additions of information to your question, and not by posting a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but this shows how to fetch a row and conditionally choose the source for an `<img>` tag:

```
# fetch the row
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=$bar"));

# determine image to show
$img = $row['field'] == 'YES' ? 'img-one.gif' : 'img-two.gif';

# output
echo "<img src=\"$img\" />";
```

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, but this sorted it! (Will accept in 4 minutes).

Comment: @Cal Happy 4k rep :) +1 from me for the use of ternary expressions.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm going to assume you have a table that's similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `some_data` varchar(128),
    `is_enabled` int(1) NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Let's say that is_enabled is the row we want to look at. You could perform something similar to the following.

```
$sql  = 'SELECT `is_enabled`';
$sql .= ' FROM `mytable`';
$sql .= ' WHERE `id` = 1234';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row['is_enabled']) {
            // This row is enabled.
        } else {
            // This row is disabled.
        }

        //Alternatively, do something like this:
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['is_enabled'] ? '/row_is_yes.gif' : '/row_is_no.gif'; ?>" />
        <?php
    }
}
```

Without more information, however, this is the most help I can give.